# Configuring JBoss and Apache for remote debugging

Tags: java, apache, jboss

I need you help to configure JBoss and Apache for remote debuging from mu IDE (Intelleji).
The JBoss and Apache are installed on remote machine . Please supply me steps how can do that .

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Have you tried putting "remote debug intellij jboss" into google? Plenty of information there.

Comment: Debugging Apache is totally different because it's not a Java application. I think JBoss is more important since your application is running in the application-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a remote-Debugging Wizard in intellyJ. 
Run -> Edit Configurations

New Remote Debug:
Host: jbosshost
Port: 1045 (default)

Now you can see the Debug Line on top of the Dialog:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1045
```

This Line must be added to your Startconfiguration of your JBoss.

run.bat or run.sh for Example

**edit:**
You can't debug the Apache-Http Webserver this way.